# How to improve this table with just one row?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[h!]
    \centerfloat
    \ra{1.3}
    \scalebox{0.7}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccccccccccccc@{}}\toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$} &
    \phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}&
    \phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}&
    \phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
    \cmidrule{1-3} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{9-11} \cmidrule{13-15}\cmidrule{17-19}
    \text{$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$} & \text{$X^2 \ (\%)$} & FGH && \text{$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$} & \text{$X^2 \ (\%)$} & FGH && \text{$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$} & \text{$X^2 \ (\%)$} & FGH && \text{$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$} & \text{$X^2 \ (\%)$} & FGH && \text{$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$} & \text{$X^2 \ (\%)$} & FGH\\ \midrule
     0 & 0 & 0 && 0 & 0 & 0 && 0 & 0 & 0 && 0 & 0 & 0 && 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

I have a table which is very wide and which has just one row. Personally I think the table looks very 'skinny' (in terms of vertical space it takes up) like this, and is also too wide. Does anyone have any tips to improve this? Any other suggestions for improvements in general that could improve the table are also appreciated!

Comment: why have a table with one row at all? Also try to avoid scaling text, especially tables with `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` it just leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is simply all the information that I need to include and I don't know how to present it otherwise. But I am fully open to suggestions. I also don't like the scaling, but it was necessary to fit it within the margins, so other ways of doing that are also appreciated.

Comment: I just meant if there is only one row you don't need a table, but actually you have two (if you include the heading) It's better to use `\small` etc rather than scaling, then you are using class specified fonts for named sizes, rather than an arbitrary scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htp]% never this: [h!]
    \centerfloat
    \ra{1.3}
% avoid scaling tables and if you do 
% you need a % after the {
%     \scalebox{0.7}{
\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccccccccccccc@{}}\toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$} &
    \phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}&
    \phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}&
    \phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
    \cmidrule{1-3} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{9-11} \cmidrule{13-15}\cmidrule{17-19}
% \text doing nothing
    $\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$&
$X^2 \ (\%)$ & FGH &&
$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$ &
$X^2 \ (\%)$ & FGH &&
$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$ &
$X^2 \ (\%)$ & FGH &&
$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$ &
$X^2 \ (\%)$ & FGH &&
$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$ &
$X^2 \ (\%)$ & FGH\\ \midrule
     0 & 0 & 0 && 0 & 0 & 0 && 0 & 0 & 0 && 0 & 0 & 0 && 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table*}


\begin{table*}[htp]% never this: [h!]
    \centerfloat
    \ra{1.3}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}\toprule
&$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$ &
$X^2 \ (\%)$ & FGH \\
\midrule
$w=8$&0&0&0\\
$w=16$&0&0&0\\
$w=32$&0&0&0\\
$w=64$&0&0&0\\
$w=128$&0&0&0\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}


    \caption{Caption}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a good suggestion. I must say that I would however probably still prefer the first option that you provided over the second option. The second option looks rather 'plain' and also automatically becomes rather small.  Your suggestions about scaling are certainly useful as well, will keep that in mind.

Comment: @TexStudent I'd never use the first version (and many journals wouldn't accept it) the fonts are already very small and it is still bleeding into the margins, to keep within the text block it would have to be unreadably small.

Comment: I just noticed some additional comments of yours: could you please elaborate on why a `%` sign is needed in case I would use scaling (which I from now on won't but still)? Also, why should I never use `[h!]`?

Comment: You are certainly right about the fact that legibility is better in the second table. However, it still looks so plain to me. Would there be any way to make it a bit more distinct?

Comment: @TexStudent an end of line is a word space so you had one on the left and not on the right so forcing the table off-centre. You should not routinely use `!` it makes so sense to routinely ignore the class specified constraints, if the constraints are unsuitable, you should change them. `[h]` (and `[h!]`) makes it more likely the float goes to the end of the document as it means not-at-top, not-at-bottom, not-on-float-page, which doesn't give latex many options to place it.

Comment: @TexStudent The second version is much better: it fits the page without having to scale it or reduce the font size and it avoids the redundant columns `$\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$ & $X^2 \ (\%)$ & FGH`.

Comment: @Alenanno Okay, I am convinced by your arguments. Would there however be a way to make the table look a bit more distinct, less plain/standard? It's a table that shows important results and currently I have the feeling that it looks nice, but rather unwitnessed.

Comment: @TexStudent I don't understand, do you want it to look "heroic"? :P

Comment: @Alenanno Well basically anything that makes it look less plain ;). The table shows some of the main results of the paper so I want it to look striking.

Comment: @TexStudent presumably the _values_ are striking if you replace `0` by your real results..  Technical tables _should_ be plain. Rules/colour/repeated headings/ are just visual distraction for people who are not interested in the data.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe you're right. I guess I'll just have to adjust my expectations a bit for now then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could make each portion its own table as in:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter

\def\ae@small@table@w{}
\def\ae@small@table@abcd{0}
\def\ae@small@table@xx{0}
\def\ae@small@table@fgh{0}

\pgfkeys{/ae/small/table/.cd,
  w/.store in=\ae@small@table@w,
  abcd/.store in=\ae@small@table@abcd,
  xx/.store in=\ae@small@table@xx,
  fgh/.store in=\ae@small@table@fgh,
}

\newcommand\mysmalltable[1][]{%%
  \bgroup
    \pgfkeys{/ae/small/table/.cd,#1}%%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}\toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w=\ae@small@table@w$} \\\midrule
    $\mathrm{ABCD}^\dag$ & $X^{2}\ (\%)$
                         & FGH \\\midrule
    $\ae@small@table@abcd$ & $\ae@small@table@xx$ 
                           & $\ae@small@table@fgh$ \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%%
  \egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
                             \hspace*{\fill}%%
\mysmalltable[w=8,abcd=0.945]\hspace*{\fill}%%
\mysmalltable[w=16,]\hspace*{\fill}%%
\mysmalltable[w=32,xx=0.004]\par\vspace{0.5cm}%%
                    \hspace*{\fill}%%
\mysmalltable[w=32,]\hspace*{\fill}%%
\mysmalltable[w=32,]\hspace*{\fill}%%
\end{minipage}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding the keys makes it a bit easier to fill in the values and know that they'll get placed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have to admit that I find the placement of the tables a bit too playful for what I had in mind, but thank you for providing a new perspective :)!

Comment: @TexStudent If the purpose of the table is to allow for easy comparison across different scenarios, then this is not a good solution and David Carlisle's is much easier to read.  I just post this as an example of how to break of the table to allow for rearrangements (however you might want to do that).

Comment: Yes, the table is mainly for comparison purposes, but thank you for showing me how to make such a split :)!